# What's the difference between Some(v) and Some(&v)?

Tags: rust

Both `code block 1` and `code block 2` in below code work, but I don't know why.
What's the difference between `Some(&number)` and `Some(number)` ?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn call(number: &str) -> &str {
    match number {
        "798-1364" => "We're sorry, please hang up and try again.",
        "645-7689" => "Hello, what can I get for you today?",
        _ => "Hi! Who is this again?"
    }
}

fn main() { 
    let mut contacts = HashMap::new();

    contacts.insert("Daniel", "798-1364");

    //====== code block 1
    match contacts.get(&"Daniel") {
        Some(&number) => println!("Calling Daniel: {}", call(&number)),
        _ => println!("Don't have Daniel's number."),
    }

    //====== code block 2, without '&'
    match contacts.get("Daniel") {
        Some(number) => println!("Calling Daniel: {}", call(number)),
        _ => println!("Don't have Daniel's number."),
    }

}
```

Comment: They are equivalent because of auto-deref and match ergonomics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `contacts.get("Daniel")` the type of the argument is `&str`.

In `contacts.get(&"Daniel")` the type of the argument is `&&str`.

The `HashMap`'s [get()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.get) method is implemented as follows:

```
pub fn get<Q: ?Sized>(&self, k: &Q) -> Option<&V>
where
    K: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Eq,
{
    self.base.get(k)
}
```

When you pass `&&str`, the Rust compiler automatically dereferences `&&str` to `&str`. As a result, both your versions are essentially equivalent.

In your `match` *arm*:

- `Some(&number)` the type of `number` is `&str`,
- `Some(number)` the type of `number` is `&&str`.

Again, due to Rust's auto-dereference rules, both are essentially the same.

Note that if you had written `Some(&&number)`, the type of `number` would have been `str` and that wouldn't compile with the message:

```
the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
```

But when you have `&&T` or even `&&&&&T`, that acts as if you had `&T`.